# Why do we convert image in arrays for image processing?

Tags: python, arrays, image, image-processing, multidimensional-array

Whenever we perform any operations with the images, we convert them into Arrays, what's the specific reason?

Comment: What other data structure would you propose using?

Comment: I mean can't we use the image directly for processing instead of converting it into arrays?

Comment: How would you read/write a particular pixel if you were accessing the image directly?

Comment: By using any data structure, well thank you! Got my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV images are stored as three-dimensional Numpy arrays. When you read in images using the library, they are represented as Numpy arrays.

With Numpy you can make blazing fast operations on numerical arrays, no matter which dimension, shape they are.